# What was the goal of the Three Circles Conspiracy?

Tags: politics, the-rcn-series

What was the goal of the Three Circles Conspiracy in the Lt. Leary/RCN series (David Drake)? Adele's parents were involved, it seems, but what was their goal? Was it a philosophical difference such as communism vs capitalism? Or just a power grab?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things (at least) that make the motives behind the "Three Circles Conspiracy" unclear.

The first thing is that all the involved characters had their own motives.

Two figures that get lots of discussion are Adele's mother and father - and in just those two examples you have different motives.

Adele's mother was an ideallist who wanted to improve things for the "common people" - despite having no real, personal knowledge of what the average, everyday person is like.  Adele knows - she spent many years living like a poor "commoner" after her parents were killed, and **knows** how romanticized her mother's concepts of average people are.

Adele's father wanted power in the government - more than he already had, that is.  He was the head of a rival political party to Corder Leary's party.  Their largest differences in political opinion seemed to have been about whose party should be in charge rather than any deep philosophical dispute or ideology.

Other people wanted power, were greedy, or just wanted to get out from under the huge debts they'd racked up.

One character (Lieutenant Estaing from the Aristoxenos in "The Far Side of the Stars") is implied to have taken part in the rebellion just to be able to play footsie with a number of women before the rebellion, and expecting not to have to take any responsibility for anything that went on before the rebellion.  He was right about not having to live up to what the women expected, but only because he went along when the Aristoxenos escaped after the rebellion failed.

So, it isn't clear what motivated those involved in the conspiracy because they all had their own motivations, and those motivations were often not (directly) political.

The other major thing that obscures the motivations for the conspiracy is that it wasn't a home grown thing driven by dissatisfaction with the existing government.

The driving force behind the "Three Circles Conspiracy" was a plan carried out by the Fifth Bureau of the Alliance of Free Stars.  That's like the KGB of the dictatorial Alliance.

The first book in the series ("With the Lightnings") starts on the planet Kostroma, right in the middle of a successful version of the "Three Circles Conspiracy."  The Alliance sent agents to provide money to and agitate existing factions in the Kostroman nobility to stage a takeover of the government.

The nobles on Kostroma apparently stage revolts anytime they feel the need to change the head of government - Adele's position as chief librarian for the head of the Kostroman government is a direct result of the previous revolt.

As Daniel and Adele are getting to know one another, some other faction of the Kostroman nobility stages another coup - but with the assistance of the Alliance agents.

The Alliance apparently routinely uses this tactic - foment dissention, provide money to local factions, takeover when infighting between factions reduces the local government to helplessness.

It worked on Kostroma, except that Daniel, Adele, Hogg, and the crew of the Aglaia managed to destroy the Alliance ships backing the revolution.  The ground troops alone weren't enough to hold Kostroma without the ships, and a Cinnabar fleet arrives in time to help put the Kostroman government back together.

The Alliance tried the same thing earlier on Cinnabar in the "Three Circles Conspiracy," but Corder Leary managed (through exceedingly harsh actions) to stop things before it reached the point that the Alliance could have taken advantage of the situation.

Other planets (without effective leaders like Corder Leary on Cinnabar) or lots of luck (Kostroma and Daniel Leary) fell to the Alliance stategy.

So, the biggest motivation behind the "Three Circles Conspiracy" was external to the people involved.  The Alliance funded any factions they could that wanted change in the Cinnabar government, making the "rebellion" a mish-mash of people with various political and personal motivations.

Many (probably most) of the participants didn't know was that Alliance agents were funding parts of the conspiracy.  Most would not have gone along if they had known - it is one thing to want to change (or take over) the government of your own planet but quite another to help your own planet be taken over by another.

The Alliance's ultimate goal was to cause enough chaos in the Cinnabar government to either be able to take over directly or at least weaken it so that it couldn't stand in the next war with the Alliance.  The long term plan of the Alliance was to take over Cinnabar and all of Cinnabar's allies - the Alliance wants to be the only major power.  The "Three Circles Conspiracy" was just one way the Alliance tried to take over Cinnabar.

---

The "Three Circles Conspiracy" is never described in detail.  Its after effects on Adele and other people are discussed in some detail in the various books.

Adele presumably knows more about it than she lets on.  She wasn't involved, but she has access to just about all computer systems on Cinnabar - private and government.

She knows enough about it that she agrees that Corder Leary reacted in probably the only way possible to keep Cinnabar from being taken over by the Alliance.

She still hates him because the Proscriptions that ended the "Three Circles Conspiracy" resulted in the death of her family, and she would kill him if she ever met him.

Because she understands the necessity of what was done, though, she pointedly avoids ever meeting Corder Leary.

---

I enjoy David Drake's books because his characters and figures are people rather than 2D cardboard cutouts.

I also like how his stories are based around real events - if you read the "Forward" sections of the books, he often describes the real life incidents from our own history which he used as the inspiration for each novel.

I find that gives the stories an authenticity that the merely fantastic stories by other authors lack.

When you read one of Drake's books and a character does something stupid, venal, or evil, you know he's not exaggerating - somebody, somewhere, somewhen in our own history was really that stupid, petty, or evil.

When the hero saves the day, you also know that somebody, somewhere, somewhen in our own history was really that lucky or that skilled.

Comment: This is great, but I have two questions left.
The first is do you remember what book this comes from?
The second is really sort of asking the question again. Obviously an author can leave a plot hole but... most revolutions or conspiracies or whatever have some sort of ideological basis or something. Kind of a 'these people in power are doing this kind of thing wrong..."
So while what you say makes sense, it doesn't define the conspiracy. Is that all that Drake gives us... I've read all the books and I don't remember more... but I haven't read much that he has written outside of the books.

Comment: It really is that way.  There are people in any society who are unhappy with how things are run.  In the Three Circles Conspiracy, the Alliance infiltrated agents to provoke and organize the dissidents.  Left to their own devices, all of those people would have griped and complained and followed more normal channels for change.  The Alliance tried to make use of them - and almost succeeded.  I'm out in the woods bicycling, so I can't dig out the books and provide quotes or point you at specific books or chapters.

Comment: Obviously in fiction one can do anything, but in real life revolutions tend to have some sort of ideological underpinning. And the name, "The Three Circles" tends to give some hint of some way they thought society should be organized, eh?

So my guess is that the alliance had some sort of ideological 'handle' on them.

Comment: Nope.  The Alliance just made use of any and all dissidents.  It works that way in real life, too.  Some few have ideals, some just want to fight, and some want power.

Comment: The "Three Circles Conspiracy" is what it was called after the fact by those who put down the uprising.  There's no mention of what those involved called it.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that. Now I am curious about why that name :) Maybe I should ask another question.